Number of points $k$ units away in discrtete $n$-dimensional space
There are some questions similar to mine, but it seems none are exactly what i'm thinking of.
So, in three dimensions, i think of the world divided into cubes. I'll assume that there are two actions per dimension. There are thus six cubes 1 unit way from a particular point.
How many cubes are two moves away? I think it is 6 (two of the same moves in each direction) + 8 (cubes diagonal to origin cube) = 14.
I want to count the farthest cubes reachable. For instance, when considering, e.g., three moves/units away, forward, backward, forward does not count. But forward, up, up counts. And forward, up, forward counts. And up, forward, up counts, etc.
In general, i am counting all cubes (points) $k$ moves (units) away from a particular cube (point), such that the reached cubes cannot be reached in less than $k$ moves.
This is a difficult problem, but i am looking for the answer to an even harder question:
How many points are reachable from a particular point exactly $k$ units away when moves must be parallel to one of the dimensions (per move) in an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space (such that every point counted cannot be reached with a series of 'dimension-parallel' moves in less than $k$ moves)?
Another way to visualize the problem is in state space (think AI planning): How many unique trajectories are there that reach states as far away as possible from one particular state - in an $n$-dimensional state space? Different trajectories may not end up in the same state.
I realize that my question has some ambiguities, but i would still appreciate potential answers, or answers to similar, more precisely stated questions.

The number of cubes 2 moves away should be 18, because the cube has 12 edges.

To rephrase your question: Consider $\mathbf Z^n$ with the norm $\| x \| = \sum_{i = 1}^n \vert x_i\vert$. Compute $N_n(k) = \#\{x \in \mathbf Z^n : \|x\| = k \}$. For $k = 0$, the result is zero, for the rest of this post assume $k>0$.
First let us consider the question with $\mathbf N_0^n$ instead of $\mathbf Z^n$. It is now about distributing the $k$ steps we are allowed to take to the $n$ dimensions. All steps go in a positive direction, otherwise we would have positive and negative steps cancelling out, so the norm would be smaller than $k$. This is a combinatorial base case called stars and bars, giving a count of $\binom{k+n-1}{k} = \binom{k+n-1}{n-1}$.
Now for $\mathbf Z^n$. Consider all elements of norm $k$ that have exactly $i$ non-zero entries. The remaining zero-entries cannot come from positive and negative steps cancelling out (see above), so there are no steps taken along the corresponding axes. For each of the $i$ non-zero entries, we have to spend at least one step along the corresponding dimension. We have $k-i$ left. Distributing them to the $i$ non-zero works exactly like in the $\mathbf N_0^n$-case as we cannot choose between positive and negative. Otherwise there would be cancelling again. This leaves us with $\binom{(k-i)+i-1}{i-1} = \binom{k-1}{i-1}$ possibilities.
Multiply them with $2^i$ for choosing the sign of the initial step for each of the non-zero entries and by $\binom{n}{i}$ for choosing which of the $n$ entries are the non-zero ones. That makes $2^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{k-1}{i-1}$. Adding over all $i$ gives the final result:
$$N_n(k) = \sum_{i=1}^n2^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{k-1}{i-1}$$
As a sanity check, for $n = 3$ this reduces to $N_3(k) = 4k^2 + 2$. Indeed, $N_3(1) = 6$ and $N_3(2) = 18$ agree with the values calculated by you and Lavender in the comments.
